# OnAppear and OnDisappear are not triggered on first view transition

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, watchos

I have a watchOS App which uses the following layout:

```swift
NavigationView {
    if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
        ContentNeedHealthKitView()
    } else if !isAuthorized {
        ContentUnauthorizedView()
    } else {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            WeightView()
                .navigationTitle("Weight")
                .tag(1)
                .onAppear {
                    print("Appear!")
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    print("Disappear!")
                }
            SettingsView()
                .navigationTitle("Settings")
                .tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `OnAppear` and `OnDisappear` actions are only executed after transitioning from on view to another **the second time**. When swiping right the first time, nothing happens.

Comment: You should put this at the end of the navigation view

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a minimal reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Also your lines are producing compiler errors. The correct way to use `onAppear` is like this:

```
.onAppear {

}
```

Here is a working example, everything is working as expected. You should also place the `onAppear` ViewModifier to the child view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct WeightView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("WeightView")
         .onAppear {
            print("Appear!")
         }
         .onDisappear {
            print("Disappear!")
         }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("SettingsView")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = 1
    @State var isAuthorized = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if !isAuthorized {
                Button("authorize") {
                    isAuthorized.toggle()
                }
            } else {
                TabView(selection: $selection) {
                    WeightView()
                        .navigationTitle("Weight")
                        .tag(1)
                    SettingsView()
                        .navigationTitle("Settings")
                        .tag(2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```